# read-only user in solr not working as expected

Tags: python, authentication, unix, solr, permissions

I would like to create two users in solr: An admin and a dev.
The dev should not be able to edit the solr metadata. This user should not be able to use solr.add or solr delete, I would like him only to be able to use solr.search for our metadata solr-core (in python pysolr).

However, the user can always use solr.add and solr.delete, no matter what permissions I set for him. Here is my security.json:

```
{
  "authentication":{
    "blockUnknown":true,
    "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials":{
      "my_admin":"<creds>",
      "my_dev":"<creds>"},
    "forwardCredentials":false,
    "":{"v":0}},
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "user-role":{
      "my_admin":["admin"],
      "my_dev":["dev"]},
    "permissions":[
      {
        "name":"security-edit",
        "role":["admin"],
        "index":1},
      {
        "name":"read",
        "role":["dev"],
        "index":2}],
    "":{"v":0}}
  }
```

I also tried `zk-read`, `metics-read`, `security-read`, `collection-admin-read` instead of `read`, always with the same result. The user my_dev can always use solr.add and solr.delete.

Comment: Have you tried using `path="/select"` to limit the user's access to only the query endpoint?

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for your hint. I tried it, but unfortunately, the my_dev still can use solr.add and solr.delete using pysolr. My permissions list looks like this:


    `"permissions":[    

      {  
        "name":"security-edit",  
        "role":["admin"],  
        "index":1},
      {
        "name":"read",
        "role":["dev"],
 "path":"/select",
        "index":2}]`

Comment: Have you tried giving `"collection":"*",` as well for the entry so that it is applied to every collection.

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried. Again with the same result. My permission list now looks like this:
     `"permissions":[  
      {  
        "name":"security-edit",  
        "role":["admin"],  
        "index":1},  
      {  
        "name":"read",  
        "role":["dev"],  
        "path":"/select",  
        "collection":"*",  
        "index":2}]`

Comment: You're missing the recommended `"name": "all", "role": ["admin"]` as the final rule; try to add that so that any other endpoint requires an admin role.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Now it works! I changed the permission list as following:

`"permissions":[
        { "name":"update", "role":["admin"] },
        { "name":"read", "role":["admin", "dev"] },
        { "name":"security-edit", "role":["admin"] },
        { "name":"all", "role":["admin"] }
    ]`

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @MatsLindh, I got it. I changed the security.json as following and now it works as expected!

```
{
  "authentication":{
    "blockUnknown":true,
    "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials":{
      "my_admin":"<...>",
      "my_dev":"<...>",
      "my_user":"<...>"},
    "forwardCredentials":false,
    "":{"v":0}},
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "user-role":{
      "my_admin":["admin"],
      "my_dev":["dev"],
      "my_user":["user"]},
    "permissions":[
        { "name":"update", "role":["admin", "dev"] },
        { "name":"read", "role":["admin", "dev", "user"] },
        { "name":"security-edit", "role":["admin"] },
        { "name":"all", "role":["admin"] }
    ]
  }
}
```